# Read Strings from an Object

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

sorry for this simple question. However, I am confused.

I want to read all Strings from the database.

Basically I am having a `EmailSettings emailAddresses = new EmailSettings()` object in my controller and want to read all emails saved in the `emailSettings Domain object`. The class looks like that:

```
class EmailSettings {

    String emailAddress

    static constraints = {

        emailAddress(blank: false, nullable: false, email: true)

    }
}
```

My problem is I do not get the saved email addresses out of the `emailAddresses` Object. I tried it with `list()`, `getEmailAddress`(like `emailAddresses.getEmailAddress().toString()`, which is `null`, even though in the db ARE email addresses saved under this domain object), but it does not work or I get an exception.

Any suggestion how to get the email addresses, which are saved in the db as an array?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: Please see Graeme's comment and my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new domain instance by newifying it, which will never give you the results that is persisted in db. To get `emailAddress` from all EmailSettings in db, you can use as:

```
EmailSetting.all*.emailAdress
```

or

```
EmailSetting.withCriteria {
    projections {
        property 'emailAddress'
    }
}
```

or can also use DetachedCriteria with above projection.

**UPDATE**
First approach will be expensive because all of the rows will be fetched and then `emailAddress` from each row will be derived. I totally missed mentioning why I had the second approach with usage of Criteria. Using Projections, you would only get the properties you would need instead of fetching the row itself. Thanks to Graeme.

Comment: Your 2 examples are very different. The first one will query for all objects in the database loading every row of the table into memory and then retrieve the property value from each object. In other words is is a very expensive operation. You’re better off with the second example, or using DetachedCriteria as mentioned

Comment: @GraemeRocher Exactly. That is why I had the second example. I missed to mention the rationale behind using a Criteria on a weekend, but I would definitely add that as an update, thanks.